# How to remove spray coating

Tags: paint, detailing

I used spray coating to protect my car from scratches but now the coating won't come off  I applied it generously because it says 'removable' but I can't clean it with standard car soap and sponge. Attaching pictures of the product. Please let me know how can I clean it from my car without damaging the original paint[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used it before, but my understanding is you have to get under it to remove it. This means, find a sharp edge and keep working it until it starts to peel.  Use only your fingernail or other soft instrument (plastic) to do this to help avoid damaging your paint. Then you should be able to get it off. Once you get one section of it going, you'll understand how to remove the rest of it. Chemicals won't work unless you get something caustic enough to damage the paint also.

In the future you should test stuff like this before you use it. That way you'll know exactly how it is going to behave.